# Size of «working» area in JScrollBar

Tags: java, swing, jscrollbar

How to define this size of JScrollBar in Swing?

[image: JScrollBar woking area size]

Comment: javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollBarUI.getTrackBounds()

Answer (score 2):

When constructing the `JScrollBar`, you can set the size of the viewable area in the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollBar.html#JScrollBar%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) using the `extent` parameter.

```
public JScrollBar(int orientation,
                  int value,
                  int extent,
                  int min,
                  int max)
```

Answer (score 1):

width - leftIcon - rightIcon. You can access the icons through javax.plaf

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `JScrollBar.getWidth()`?